# How to prevent user from logging in from multiple browsers at the same time in codeigniter?

Tags: php, html, mysql, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter-3

I have ticket system active. What I want that when a user logs in from chrome, then again if he tries to log in again from firefox without logging out from chrome then the chrome account will be automatically logged out.

here is my controller code:-

```
public function loginSubmit() {
        if($this->session->userdata('is_logged_in')==true){
            $sessionData = $this->session->all_userdata();
            $userId = $sessionData['id'];
            redirect('auth/welcome');
        }
        else{
                $userId = $this->input->post('id');
                $u_data = array (
                    'id' => $userId,
                    'is_logged_in' => TRUE
                );
                $this->session->set_userdata($u_data);
                $sessionId = session_id();
                $this->auth_model->setSession($userId,$sessionId);
                redirect('auth/welcome');
                $this->login();
        }
    }
```

here is my model code:-

```
public function setSession($userId, $sessionId) {
        $data1 = array(
            'id' => $userId
        );
        $oldSessionId = $this->db->select("session_id")
                ->where($data1)
                ->get("client_sign_up")
                ->row('session_id');
        print_r($oldSessionId);
        $data = array(
            'id' => $oldSessionId
        );
        $this->db->where('id',$data)
                ->delete('ci_sessions',$u_data);
        $this->db->where('id', $userId)
                ->update('client_sign_up', array('session_id' => $sessionId));
    }
```

Comment: use something like token, and reset token when user login.

Comment: Add a username and a useragent columns into the database.. And delete other sessions which not match the current logging in browser useragent..

Comment: Similar to @RaymondNijland, on a site I built, the username is kept in the session table, so if the user logs in a second time, the first session is removed.  Only one session per username allowed.